# Call "Environment variables" dialog from Win-r

Tags: windows, shortcuts, environment-variables

In Windows, if one presses <kbd>Win-r</kbd>, and types there, e.g. `control` the control panel opens. Is there a <kbd>Win-r</kbd> shortcut for environment variables dialog?

Comment: `cmd /c "set & pause"`

Comment: @akira: nice trick. Did not know about that. Thanks. However the dialog is preferable, since I'm doing a tutorial which is aimed for users and I don't want to give instuctions for some particular version of windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dialog you are refering to is a subdialog in the

```
C:\Windows\System32\systempropertiesadvanced.exe
```

program. Just call that.

Answer (score 0):

To open the ***Environment Variables***

In <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, opening the Run ***Dialogue Box***, put

**SystemPropertiesAdvanced** this will open-up the Environment Variables Dialogue box.

[win_r_system_properties_advanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlcdX.png)

Image [swapreference](https://www.swapreference.com/)